# Pipeline Cache setup issues

Tags: caching, azure-devops, msbuild

I may be approaching the new Cache pipeline task the wrong way, but I'm trying to improve the Build task. Currently, the build task takes on average 20 minutes to complete. I've been reading about the new Cache task, but it seems that would help with caching items like Nuget and npm libraries which for us is in a different task and only takes 1 minute.

Is there a cache setup that can help with the build itself?

Comment: Not get your latest information, is the workaround helpful for you? Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 0):

Caching is especially useful in scenarios where the same dependencies are downloaded over and over at the start of each run. This is often a time consuming process involving hundreds or thousands of network calls.

Caching can be effective at improving build time provided the time to restore and save the cache is less than the time to produce the output again from scratch. Because of this, caching may not be effective in all scenarios and may actually have a negative impact on build time.
Please refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/caching?view=azure-devops) for details.

Here are two other ways to reduce build time:

1. You can try to reduce build time in CI pipelines through parallel builds. Here are the reference: [blog1](https://medium.com/@mehmetugurgural/reducing-longer-build-times-in-ci-pipelines-parallel-builds-build-agents-with-azure-devops-8aa5c22987f8),[blog2](http://www.getlatestversion.it/2019/07/12/reduce-your-build-time-with-parallelism-in-azure-devops/).
2. In order to obtain faster performance, you can use private agent to run the build pipeline, as private agents cache everything between builds. If you do need to clean the repo (for example to avoid problems caused by residual files from a previous build), you can select [Clean option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic#clean-build) in build definition.

**.NET/NuGet**:

If you use `PackageReferences` to manage NuGet dependencies directly within your project file and have `packages.lock.json` file(s), you can enable caching by setting the `NUGET_PACKAGES` environment variable to a path under `$(Pipeline.Workspace)` and caching this directory.

Comment: Unfortunately, we can't do parallel builds because of the way our application is constructed. We recently moved our build agents to a VM to have more processing power and memory.

Comment: I looked at the NuGet caching, but it seems the instructions are geared for only Core projects; not Framework.

Comment: @ja67 By default, `PackageReference` is used for .NET Core projects,but .NET Framework projects also support `PackageReference`.To use PackageReference , you only need to migrate `packages.config` to `packagereference`, so you can use nuget caching. Here is a [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files#project-type-support) you can refer to .